# Core Plot : Grid lines don't appear when labeling policy is not automatic

Tags: ios, core-plot

Am trying to plot a simple statistics using Core Plot in an iPhone App. I initially used the labeling policy as CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic for both the axes, and the grid lines appeared fine as here :

[image]

You can see that the graph has both vertical and horizontal grid lines. Then, I changed the labeling policy to

```
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:xAxisLabels.count];
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
textStyle.color = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];

for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc]
                              initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSDate *)[xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++]] textStyle:textStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.rotation = 25.0;
    newLabel.offset = 10.0;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
}
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

But, since when I added custom labeling for X-Axis, the X-Axis grid lines (i.e. the vertical ones) are not appearing. Only horizontal grid lines are seen, as you can see in the below screenshot from the App :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, @Erik Skroch ! What worked for me was a simple change in the labeling policy from

```
axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

to

```
 axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
```

This was instigated by your statement :
"The CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone labeling policy does not create any labels or tick marks."

Answer (score 8):

The `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy does not create any labels or tick marks. You need to create sets of locations and set the `majorTickLocations` and/or `minorTickLocations`.

Here's some sample code from the *Plot Gallery* example app:

```
NSSet *majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber zero],
                             [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:30],
                             [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:50],
                             [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:85],
                             [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:100],
                             nil];
xAxis.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
```

The tick locations are often the same as the label locations, but they don't have to be.